# Interactive Web Maps That Update as Users Change Attributes

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, google-maps, google-earth

I want to create an interactive map where users can go to the website, click on a polygon in the map, and have a chioce of three options. When they click one, it will change the color and update the attribute.

I want to have a split screen showing images from Google Earth (the image would be the same location but a different time period) and a outline of polygons overlaid on it. The user would ideally click the polygon and have a choice of red, yellow, or green pop up. They would then chose the color, and in the background the attribute for that polygon will change.

How would I go about doing this? I am new to web mapping.Thanks.

Comment: Websockets is the future of real-time mapping - open the editing application and display application side-by-side and see it in action http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Bringing-Real-Time-Data-to-the-Web-A-Live-Example-using-Node-js-Pusher-and-FME-Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fairly big question, a good place to start would be investigating different client-side api's for creating web maps.  Some great ones include:

- [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/)
- [esri's javascript api](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/)
- [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/)
- [google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)

Part of your decision will be based on if your application will be commercial.  If so, I recommend leaflet.

These api's also tie into different server-side options.  For example, if you are using ArcGIS Server to serve up geometry/tiles, then definitely look closely at esri's javascript api.

I recommend choosing an api and begin coding.  From there, you can ask additional and more targeted questions in the forum and get responses.  For example:

- how can i add geojson polygon to a leaflet map?
- how can i integrate / sync my mapbox map with a google earth view?
- how can i dynamically change the symbology of my esri graphics layer?

Hope this gets you started.